# Flutter: how to create a Singleton from an http request

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I want to declare a user object, that I will instantiate with an http request, and I want it to be global. How can I do it? With a Singleton? But how can I make this class also a Singleton? Or is there another way?
That is what I've done so far:

```
class User{
String username;
String password;
  int id;

User({this.username, this.id});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
      username: json['name'],
      id: json['id']
    );
  }

}
```

and then:

```
var user = await login(username, password, context);
```

Comment: You really don't want Singletons in your app.  I think what you really want is a way to access a `User` object that is shared near the top of your Widget tree.  You could use something like [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model).  This way you can define your `User` object as a Model, complete with methods to perform login, wrap the `ScopedModel<User>` around your root and use `ScopedModelDescendant<User>` where ever you have login buttons or User name text labels.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but if I use _Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil_, does the _scopedModelDescendant_ find the user object or won't?

Comment: `Navigator.of` is going to search up the widget hierarchy until it finds the closest NavigatorState.  If you only provide navigation using the WidgetsApp or MaterialApp, then that's the widget it will find.  This means that as long as you wrap your App with the `ScopedModel<User>` then the scoped model descendants will be able to find it, even if you change routes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In flutter, you should not make singletons. Instead, you should store it into a widget that exposes these data to all of its descendants. 
Usually `InheritedWidget`

The reason being, with such architecture all the descendants are automatically aware of any change made to your "singleton".

A typical example would be the following:

```
@immutable
class User {
  final String name;

  User({this.name});
}

class Authentificator extends StatefulWidget {
  static User currentUser(BuildContext context) {
    final _AuthentificatorScope scope = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_AuthentificatorScope);
    return scope.user;
  }

  final Widget child;

  Authentificator({this.child, Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthentificatorState createState() => _AuthentificatorState();
}

class _AuthentificatorState extends State<Authentificator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _AuthentificatorScope(
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _AuthentificatorScope extends InheritedWidget {
  final User user;

  _AuthentificatorScope({this.user, Widget child, Key key}) : super(child: child, key: key);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_AuthentificatorScope oldWidget) {
    return user != oldWidget.user;
  }
}
```

which you have to instantiate like this:

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Authentificator(
      child: child,
    );
  },
  home: Home(),
);
```

and then use inside your pages like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  User user = Authentificator.currentUser(context);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but if I use _Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil_, would it work the same?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that

Comment: for example, in the _scoped model_, it goes over the Widget tree. I don't know if _remove_ will delete these relationships or not. Probably not, but just asking

Comment: No the navigator stack and the widget tree are unrelated

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In this example, `MaterialApp` is providing the NavigatorState and handling the routing.  Because `builder: (context, child)` is specified, MaterialApp will pass the Navigator as `child` to the builder function, who in turn wraps the child with the `Authentificator`.  This means routing is done below `Authentificator` and navigation doesn't remove the `Authentificator`.  Therefore, `Navigator.of` will search up the widget hierarchy and stop before `Authentificator`.

Comment: @JamesPoag Actually it's the opposite. `Authentificator` will be a child of `Navigator`. (So that your authent can redirect to a login route)

Comment: @RémiRousselet Ok, I must be misunderstanding [the documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L268).  My assumption is that if you forgo including the `child` in the builder result that the _"the application will have no navigator"_ meant that somehow the Navigator was apart of the child production.

Comment: `child` is the current route :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that bit.  My logical disconnect is when reading [this passage](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L277) in the docs.  They only way I can think of this to work is if NavigatorState is appended to the child production of the route builder.  In any event, `Authentificator ` always wraps the heirarchy.